# object has no attribute problem with python code

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class

I'm doing a project to create the database of an airline(simple) with python 3.

It contains three different codes: Aircraft, Flight and Airline. All three codes work together and both Aircraft and Flight work correctly. The problem is with the Airline one.

The code is executed with a test code. That test code contains all the information from the planes and flights. That information is saved in two different classes which are called later by the Airline program.

The problem comes when I try to call the Airline.fleet(and also operations and schedule) from the class CAirline.

The program returns:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'fleet'
```

The Airline code is:

```
import Aircraft
import Flight

def Airline():
    class CAirline:
        def __init__(self):
            self.name = ""
            self.fleet = ""
            self.operations = ""
            self.schedule = ""

    return CAirline


def add_aircraft(a, ac):
    a=[Airline() for i in range(10)]
    j=0
    while j<len(a.fleet):
        if a[j].fleet[0]==ac[0]:
            return False
        else:
            a.fleet.append(ac)
            return True
        j+=1
```

The test code is:

```
import Aircraft
import Flight
import Airline

def createXicaAirline ():


    AC1 = Aircraft.Aircraft()
    AC1.callsign = "EC234"
    AC1.type = "A320"
    AC1.seats = 280

    AC2 = Aircraft.Aircraft()
    AC2.callsign = "EC504"
    AC2.type = "A321"
    AC2.seats = 310


    FL1 = Flight.Flight()
    FL1.dep = "Barcelona"
    FL1.arr = "Budapest"
    FL1.time_dep = 8*60
    FL1.time_arr = 11*60
    FL1.passengers = 54

    FL2 = Flight.Flight()
    FL2.dep = "Barcelona"
    FL2.arr = "Istambul"
    FL2.time_dep = 9*60
    FL2.time_arr = 12.5*60
    FL2.passengers = 154

    FL3 = Flight.Flight()
    FL3.dep = "Istambul"
    FL3.arr = "Budapest"
    FL3.time_dep = 17*60
    FL3.time_arr = 19.25*60
    FL3.passengers = 140

    FL4 = Flight.Flight()
    FL4.dep = "Budapest"
    FL4.arr = "Barcelona"
    FL4.time_dep = 20*60
    FL4.time_arr = 23*60
    FL4.passengers = 97


    Xica = Airline.Airline()
    Xica.name = "Xica Airline"
    Airline.add_aircraft(Xica, AC1)
    Airline.add_aircraft(Xica, AC2)
    Airline.add_operation(Xica, FL1)
    Airline.add_operation(Xica, FL2)
    Airline.add_operation(Xica, FL3)
    Airline.add_operation(Xica, FL4)
    return Xica

print ("Phase1 test program")
A = createXicaAirline()
Airline.show_airline(A)
print ("Phase1 test program end")
```

The code runs perfectly until: Airline.add_aircraft(Xica, AC1)

Comment: Why are you defining the class inside a function?

Comment: And did you mean to end `Airline()` with `return CAirline()` so it returns an instance rather than the class itself?

Comment: You assign a list to ``a`` with ``a=[...`` in ``add_aircraft``. Why do you expect ``a`` to be an ``Airline``?

Comment: You may also lookup test frameworks (e.g. `unittest` or `pytest`) if you want to write tests.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here;

```
a=[Airline() for i in range(10)]
j=0
while j<len(a.fleet):
```

You probably accidentally left that top line in there by accident, because it overwrites what you pass in to the function

As a tip, you can help avoid these problems by using more descriptive variable names. So instead of `a`, you could call it `airlines` or `airline_list`

Comment: `Airline()` returns the class, not an instance. Doesn't he also need to call `airline()` to get an instance?

Comment: @Barmar Oops, you are right, completely missed that. This code is quite weird, I wonder why the OP did that